# Do I have to distribute intermediary formats of my adaption?

Tags: creative-commons, cc-by-sa, artistic-works

There's a website that I really like which is licensed under CC-BY-SA. I've always thought it would work really well as a physical book too, and so I've decided to try to make it happen.

I'm planning on selling copies afterwards, not because I'm aiming to make a huge profit but just because it will take a bit of an investment from me to convert it, and I'd like to recoup some of that.

As I understand it, this is permissible by CC-BY-SA provided that I license my printed copies as CC-BY-SA also, as well as providing attribution. What I'm not so sure about is how far I have to go to comply with this.

Is it sufficient for me to just notify readers that they can scan or photocopy the book, or do I have to distribute the PDFs that I used to print it? I'm going to use an automated process to do much of the conversion, do I also have to release my code under CC-BY-SA?

Comment: Related: [Does the CC-BY-SA License require that source code of derivative works be shared?](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1849/1212) I think that answers most of your question, but I'm not sure whether it's a perfect duplicate.

Comment: Thanks! I think one of the examples they specify is relevant: "I publish a CC-BY-SA printed book that uses a CC-BY-SA illustration. I am not required to publish my manuscript or layout files so that someone could print the book with a different illustraction. However, I must link to the original image."

@amon Do you want to post that link and a little bit of blurb around it as an answer and I'll accept it?